# xticks in hv.Bars with plotly not showing correctly

Tags: plotly-python, holoviews

I am trying to use `hv.Bars` with `Plotly` but the xticks on my plot are cut off. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I finally solved this by adding a hook that changes the margin property:

```
def hook(plot, element):
    plot.handles["layout"]["margin"]["l"] = 150 
    plot.handles["layout"]["margin"]["b"] = 150
```

Documentation on how to use the hooks is [here](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#Plot-hooks).